# What is meant by Error 1451 in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database

I simply ran the delete query in my sql-yog and i was carried away by this error.
Can anyone give me a explanation for my error.

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_lakshyaassets3`.`lss_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_lss_entity_aid` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `lss_address` (`address_id`))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the properties of `FOREIGN KEY` constraint is that it is used to prevent actions that would destroy links between tables. Therefore you cannot delete rows in a table which shares a FOREIGN KEY constraints with another table without deleting in parent first.

You can handle this in 2 ways:

- Use Foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE` (which will delete child rows if parent is deleted) [reference](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/)
- Use Foreign key with `ON DELETE NO ACTION` (which deletes the parent without exceptions, but your data will become meaningless)

You are getting this error because default property is `ON DELETE RESTRICT`

HTH

Comment: Thank you so much buddy , these properties which you sent me was very helpful to me. I understood the ways to DELETE.. nice of you !

Answer (score 0):

There is foreign key that points to   that table....that is the reason you cannot delete it.
You have to delete **first** the row in the child table...the child table is the referencing table.The foreign key is contained in the child table

Comment: The error has occurred because we cannot delete a row which has a foreign key assigned to it. Example : I have a foreign key called 'address_id' assigned to it. Thanks Dimitris..!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by removing the foreign key constraint check the following link

http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/05/09/how-to-remove-foreign-keys-in-mysql/

Once you remove and delete the data then you can again add the foreign key constraint.  Use alter query from the following link

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reference buddy, i have used  the reference which you sent..!